# Interaction tests in Vue with Storybook

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, storybook

The Storybook [documentation](https://storybook.js.org/testing/react-ui-testing/) mentions testing, but documents only React. How can I set up integration (specifically, [interaction](https://storybook.js.org/testing/interaction-testing/)) tests for a Vue project?

Comment: According to: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html, you should check http://karma-runner.github.io/2.0/index.html, and according to the links you shared, karma guidelines are here: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/karma.md

Comment: Storybook has a [guide for Vue](https://storybook.js.org/basics/guide-vue/). I found Storybook to fail miserably in my project. I also dislike documenting the code with JS (I much prefer Markdown instead). I switched to [`vue-styleguidist`](https://github.com/vue-styleguidist/vue-styleguidist) which works quite well.

Comment: @Erubiel Vue's unit test guide doesn't cover interaction testing, which is why I was looking at storybook, which apparently supports it, but only for React (?).

Comment: @tony19 The guide for Vue in Storybook doesn't mention _testing_. Also I can't seem to understand how to write tests for Markdown. I'm pretty Markdown would fail miserably when you try writing an assertion.

Comment: That's true. I didn't try the "testing" features of Storybook, whatever they may be. I don't use the styleguide for testing, so that's not what I meant by "failing miserably". I use the styleguide for documenting use cases of components.